# Android safety question using android exported

Tags: android

I'm not an android dev. I used capacitor to convert a web app into an android app. The new sdk 31 changes have required me to add `android:exported=true` onto the mainActivity tag in androidManifest.xml file since it has intent filters. Basically, in order for my app to be approved by google console I need to add this one property.

ELI5 - is this safe, what does this do ?

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"   <---------------------------- this
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
        >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to use exported true is used correctly
The exported attribute is used to define if an activity, service, or receiver in your app is accessible and can be launched from an external application.

As a practical example, if you try to share a file you’ll see a set of applications available. Clicking on one of them will open the activity responsible to handle that file, which means that it’s declared on the Manifest with exported:true.

For more details https://cafonsomota.medium.com/android-12-dont-forget-to-set-android-exported-on-your-activities-services-and-receivers-3bee33f37beb